# Creating and displaying full details

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have mini forum site im coding and when users make their profile they get to add a little info about themselves. I want them to be able to make list elements and add images into this description, as well as make /n (drop a line). How can I do this from a simple input text area? is there any jQuery text area plugins someone can recommend.

As it stands I have the users start any list elements (bullet points) with *** and then just septate out the lines and stick them in list elements, for images I make them upload the image, they get a ref number and put that in the box between two sets of ++.

This is not very user friendly, anyone have any suggestions or plug-ins i could use to better this?

Comment: what have u tried so far??can u show the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a HTML editor such as [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php). This will change a textarea into a HTML editor, which will give your users the ability to format the content with lists and images etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following plugins available for your need. [CL Editor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/), [CK Editor] (http://ckeditor.com/), [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php).